# protobuf validator command generates file in wrong path

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc-go, protobuf-go

I am trying to include request validation for grpc. I modified the protobuf command like this.
`pkg/test/test.proto` contains my schema.

If i run the below command :

```
protoc --go_out=. \
--proto_path=${GOPATH}/src \
--proto_path=${GOPATH}/src/github.com/gogo/protobuf/gogoproto/ \
--proto_path=${GOPATH}/src/github.com/mwitkow/go-proto-validators/ \
--proto_path=. \ --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative pkg/test/test.proto --govalidators_out=.
```

The `validator.go` file generated file is not generated inside pkg/test instead it is getting generated inside a new folder created `{source relative pkg}/pkg/test/test.proto/validator.go`.

How to generate `validator.go` file without the folder structure in `pkg/test`?

Comment: Dear @Prems, Thank you for the bounty! It looks like the answer has helped you to solve the problem. Please, consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Analysis

It looks like the `*.validator.pb.go` files are generated in the wrong directory.

Using the `pkg/test/test.proto` file with the following content:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option go_package = "github.com/example-user/example-repository";

service Greeter {
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}

message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

Produced the file system contents:

```
$ find .
.
./github.com
./github.com/example-user
./github.com/example-user/example-repository
./github.com/example-user/example-repository/test.validator.pb.go
./pkg
./pkg/test
./pkg/test/test_grpc.pb.go
./pkg/test/test.proto
./pkg/test/test.pb.go
```

## Solution

Add the `--govalidators_opt=paths=source_relative` command line argument.

Please, note the parameter name:

> `--govalidators_opt`

The complete command line:

```
protoc --go_out=. \
    --proto_path=. \
    --go_opt=paths=source_relative \
    --go-grpc_out=. \
    --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative \
    --govalidators_out=. \
    --govalidators_opt=paths=source_relative \
    pkg/test/test.proto
```

Produced the file system contents:

```
$ find .
.
./pkg
./pkg/test
./pkg/test/test_grpc.pb.go
./pkg/test/test.proto
./pkg/test/test.pb.go
./pkg/test/test.validator.pb.go
```

## Additional references

- Seems to be an example. [Comment](https://github.com/mwitkow/go-proto-validators/issues/75#issuecomment-852704315).
- A GitHub issue created by the asker? [How to specify path for generated validator.go ? · Issue #121 · mwitkow/go-proto-validators](https://github.com/mwitkow/go-proto-validators/issues/121).